# Join table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have an unfinished table structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>color</td>
    <td>age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to append the following rows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td>brown</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>black</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mouse</td>
    <td>grey</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So that the final table looks like that:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>color</td>
    <td>age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td>brown</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>black</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mouse</td>
    <td>grey</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm creating that table dynamically, in an each-loop, so row by row.

That is my approach:

```
// 1st iteration
tr = "<tr><td>dog</td><td>brown</td><td>5</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(1)').append(tr)

// 2nd iteration
tr = "<tr><td>cat</td><td>white</td><td>3</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(1)').append(tr)
```

But the result doesn't look as intended.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zsvhthvh/).

Comment: a `<tr>` can't be a child of another `<tr>` so clearly `append()` won't work

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration you should append *tr* body in existing row (without parent tag).
In the second iteration you should put *tr* after existing row.

```js
/* The rows to append
 <tr><td>dog</td><td>brown</td><td>5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>cat</td><td>white</td><td>3</td></tr>
 <tr><td>cat</td><td>black</td><td>7</td></tr>
 <tr><td>mouse</td><td>grey</td><td>2</td></tr>
*/

// 1st iteration
tr = "<tr><td>dog</td><td>brown</td><td>5</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(1)').append($(tr).html())

// 2nd iteration
tr = "<tr><td>cat</td><td>white</td><td>3</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(1)').after(tr)

// 3rd iteration
tr = "<tr><td>cat</td><td>black</td><td>7</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(3)').append($(tr).html())

// 4th iteration
tr = "<tr><td>mouse</td><td>grey</td><td>2</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(3)').after(tr)
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>color</td>
    <td>age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The first iteration should only include the `<td>`s and not a `<tr>` since you are adding it to an existing row. You don't want to append a `<tr>` to another `<tr>`
2. Use `after()` in the second iteration. Here you should use a `<tr>`

Try changing it to something like this:

```
// 1st iteration
tr = "<td>dog</td><td>brown</td><td>5</td>";
$('table tr:eq(1)').append(tr)

// 2nd iteration
tr = "<tr><td>cat</td><td>white</td><td>3</td></tr>";
$('table tr:eq(1)').after(tr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add row number every odd list item. That way you can add as many 
item as possible to your table.

```js
var data = [
  '<tr><td>dog</td><td>brown</td><td>5</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>cat</td><td>white</td><td>3</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>cat</td><td>black</td><td>7</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>mouse</td><td>grey</td><td>2</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>dog</td><td>brown</td><td>5</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>cat</td><td>white</td><td>3</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>cat</td><td>black</td><td>7</td></tr>',
  '<tr><td>mouse</td><td>grey</td><td>2</td></tr>'
];

var rowNo = 1;
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  var $current = $(data[i]); // Converting data to jQuery item.
  
  // On every odd row add row Number cell to the begining of <tr> tag.
  if ((i + 1) % 2 == 1) {
   $current.prepend('<td rowspan="2">' + rowNo + '</td>');
    rowNo++;
  }
  
  $('table').append($current);
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>color</td>
    <td>age</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also updated your JSFiddle. Check this out: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zsvhthvh/3/)