# Dynamically append multiple TRs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, html-table

I have the following array:

```
arr = [{
  "ID": 1,
  "animals": {
    "dog": {
      "color": "brown",
      "age": 5
    },
    "cat": {
      "color": "white",
      "age": 3
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": 2,
  "animals": {
    "cat": {
      "color": "black",
      "age": 7
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": 3,
  "animals": {
    "mouse": {
      "color": "white",
      "age": 1
    },
    "dog": {
      "color": "black",
      "age": 9
    },
    "cat": {
      "color": "grey",
      "age": 4
    }
  }
}]
```

I need to make this table out of that:

[image: desired table]

Or as code:

```
<table border="1" id="myTab">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Color</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>brown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">2</td>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">3</td>
    <td>mouse</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>white</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>grey</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114959/join-table-rows) I learned the right way how to merge multiple `tr`.

But still, it won't work in my example:

```
$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
  var rowspan = Object.keys(arr[key].animals).length;

  var tr = "";
  c = 0;
  $.each(value, function(key2, value2) {
    if (key2 != "animals") {
      if (rowspan < 1) {
        rowspan = 1;
      }
      tr += '<td rowspan=' + rowspan + '>' + value2 + '</td>';
    } else {
      $.each(value2, function(key3, value3) {
        var tr2_temp = "";

        tr2_temp += "<td>" + key3 + "</td>";
        $.each(value3, function(key4, value4) {
          tr2_temp += "<td>" + value4 + "</td>";
        });

        if (c == 0) {
          $('#myTab tr:eq(' + parseInt(key + 1) + ')').append(tr2_temp)
          c++;
        } else {
          $('#myTab tr:eq(' + parseInt(key + 1) + ')').after(tr2_temp)
          c = 0;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $('#myTab > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>' + tr + '</tr>');
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwx6nk8p/).

Comment: If you were to hardcode your table Markup, based on the array, what is the table structure you want to see as an output? Based on just the code, there seems to be some logical choices you make so seeing what the actual output is you expect helps a lot.

Comment: @Fran: I added the code of the desired table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
arr = [{
  "ID": 1,
  "animals": {
    "dog": {
      "color": "brown",
      "age": 5
    },
    "cat": {
      "color": "white",
      "age": 3
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": 2,
  "animals": {
    "cat": {
      "color": "black",
      "age": 7
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": 3,
  "animals": {
    "mouse": {
      "color": "white",
      "age": 1
    },
    "dog": {
      "color": "black",
      "age": 9
    },
    "cat": {
      "color": "grey",
      "age": 4
    }
  }
}]

function getAttr(obj) {
 var props;
 for (var prop in obj) {
    props += '<td>'+obj[prop]+'</td>';
  }
  return props;
}

function extractChildren(animal,obj) {
    return '<td>'+animal+'</td>' + getAttr(obj) + '';
}
function addRows() {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var children = [];
    var rows = 0;

    for (var prop in arr[i].animals) {
      rows++;
      children.push(extractChildren(prop,arr[i].animals[prop]));
    }
    $('#tbl tbody').append(
    `<tr>
        <td rowspan="`+rows+`">`+ arr[i].ID+ `</td>`+children[0]+`
    </tr>`
    );
    children.shift();
    for(var j=0; j<children.length; j++) {
        $('#tbl tbody').append(`<tr>`+children[j]+`</tr>`);
    }
    }
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    addRows();
});
</script>
<table id="tbl" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Colour</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: `thead` ,`tfoot` and `tbody` are optional and attaching elements to the DOM inside a loop as well as doing a `.find` is the most inefficient way of doing it and can slow down the rendering of the page with less than 100 rows processed.

Comment: They are optional but are completely valid, the op asked about dynamically adding TR's so how would we avoid attaching elements to the DOM? Your answer also uses a loop with append. But correct the find isn't needed i've adjusted the answer

Comment: I don't attach to the DOM within the loop as that would be extremely bad. I attach into memory and only after I'm done attach to the DOM 1 time only. In regards to the table markup, we usually try to give answers using given markup (unless it is invalid to begin with) in case OP cannot change it and then leave a recommendation to improve it if possible. Imagine basing a solution on amended markup the user cannot change :( However, in this case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend you don't use the animal type as a property name, as that causes issues if you have multiple of the same type of animal but instead use a property, possibly, named `type` with the value of `dog, cat, etc..`, using your existing conditions you can do it like below.

In addition, I recommend you write to a variable in memory first and then do a single append to the DOM.

```js
arr = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "animals": {
        "dog": {
            "color": "brown",
            "age": 5
        },
        "cat": {
            "color": "white",
            "age": 3
        }
    }
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "animals": {
        "cat": {
            "color": "black",
            "age": 7
        }
    }
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "animals": {
        "mouse": {
            "color": "white",
            "age": 1
        },
        "dog": {
            "color": "black",
            "age": 9
        },
        "cat": {
            "color": "grey",
            "age": 4
        }
    }
}]

var rowspanTemplate = '<tr><td rowspan="{0}">{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td></tr>'
var simpleTemplate = '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'
var $newRows = $('<div></div>');

$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
    var newRow;
    var animalTypes = Object.keys(value.animals);
    var i;
    var animalType;

    for (i = 0; i < animalTypes.length; i++) {
        animalType = animalTypes[i];

        if (i === 0) {
            newRow = rowspanTemplate
                .replace('{0}', animalTypes.length)
                .replace('{1}', value.ID)
                .replace('{2}', animalType)
                .replace('{3}', value.animals[animalType].color)
                .replace('{4}', value.animals[animalType].age)
        } else {
            newRow = simpleTemplate
                .replace('{0}', animalTypes[i])
                .replace('{1}', value.animals[animalType].color)
                .replace('{2}', value.animals[animalType].age)
        }

        $newRows.append($(newRow));
    }
})

$('#myTab').append($newRows.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="myTab">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Color</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In my real case there are >20 different columns. Is there any way, to make it more dynamically, instead of replacing every one of them?

Comment: @user1170330 You can use angular, knockout or similar to do it for you but for a simple mapping such as this I wouldn't introduce a heavy dependency like that, unless you are already using them :) Even with 100 columns, you only have to write the mapper ones, that's it. Make it a function, pass in the part of the array and it returns the `tr` with the mapped values. That way you can also write unit tests against the mapper independently. You can also write a `string.format` extensions passing the array of parameters that replace `{x}` with values in the same position dynamically.